# трёхпотоковое видео на одноплатнике

Tags: python, linux

Всем привет, задача вести в течение хотя бы дня трёхпотоковое видео на одноплатнике, подскажите по каким характеристикам нужно подбирать железо?

Пробовал на различных одноплатниках и компах:

1. Распбери пай 4, использовал библиотеку opencv на python, не потянуло даже одно видео с камеры разрешением 1080 на 720, ос была raspbian
2. Рок пи 4, та же ситуация, что и с распбери, ос была ubuntu desktop
3. Khadas VIM4, аналогично остальным, хотя сам микрокомпьютер в разы мощнее, чем вышеупомянутые, ос была ubuntu server(headless)
   Есть предположение, что дело в прошивках процессора, так как пробовал на ноутбуке Lenovo, максимально простой, он потянул одно видео разрешением 1080 на 720.
   Если есть какие-то ошибки в рассуждениях, не обессудьте, я в этом ноль.

Comment: в причем здесь питон?

Comment: @strawdog, знаю python решил на нём написать

Comment: питон очень медленный язык, он не предназначен для таких задач. Надо использовать компилируемые языки. И глубоко оптимизировать код, задействуя специализированные наборы инструкций процессора. А при доступности хоть какого то видеоадаптера, то и его возможности тоже. хотя сомневаюсь что на одноплатниках такое водится

Comment: Хотя конечно вопрос сколько работы выполняет opencv и сколько питон.

Comment: @Mike, то есть на python это сделать невозможно? Фишка в том, что один и тот же скрипт по разному работал на разных устройствах, к примеру, на далеко не самом мощном мини компе от асус трёхпотоковое видео работало близко к правде, через 30-40 минут начались небольшие задержки, обрывки

Comment: Я не знаю на сколько и как именно для обработки используется opencv. сам питон медленный, но его библиотеки обычно написаны на C и хорошо оптимизированы, за счет них он часто выигрывает. И может оказаться что на "не самом мощном asus" была более подходящая видеокарта, возможности которой и задействовал opencv

Comment: @Mike, понял, попробую отталкиваться от mcu, спасибо

Comment: @Mike, есть ли варианты с подходящим графическим процессором или источники, где можно найти?

Comment: [Люди делают](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-set-up-real-time-video-using-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4/), правда на меньшем разрешении. `на далеко не самом мощном мини компе ... работало` - CPU отличаются внезапно не только частотой, но и набором инструкций и прочими вещами. Например, после добавления инструкций sha256 отпала проблема "HTTPS грузит процессор сервера".

Comment: @TotalPusher, то, что люди делают распознавание с одной камерой и различные преобразования, но трёхпотокового видео через opencv я не находил в просторах интернета, сам писал opencv в связке с multiprocessing, но всё равно тщетно, нужен либо графический процессор посерьёзнее, как на многопотоковых видеорегистраторах, но опять же, нет ни одного одноплтаника с таким же граф процессором, как на тех многопотоковых регистраторах, либо уходить от opencv на что-то другое

Comment: Если отключить 2 потока, то один поток тянет? Тогда проблема в железе. Если нет - значит в коде, у людей же работает. По производительности железа - попробовать запрофилировать, посмотреть системные вызовы. Я бы в этом направлении шел. Может быть, нужно перебилдить библиотеку с какими-то специальными настройками. Тут вам вряд ли с этим помогут, есть более специализированные форумы, в том числе зарубежные.

Comment: @TotalPusher,  с разрешением в 1080 на 720 к сожалению ни один одноплатник не тянет из выше перечисленных, возможно посмотрю системные вызовы, однако появилась идея смастерить связку голой платы многопотокового видеорегистратора такого типа "Xm оригинальный 5Mp 4Ch Dvr HiSilicon Hi3520Dv300" с любым другим одноплатником. Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: Я не уверен, что средний одноплатник потянет даже простое декодирование 720p видео в H.264 на центральном процессоре в реальном времени. А уж CV к нему применять...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос откуда и куда вести видео и какая обработка требуется на нем

Comment: Что имеется в виду под фразой «вести»? Если задача — брать видео с подключенной камеры, то, может, проще готовую ip-камеру с готовым видеопотоком купить?)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, через ffmpeg прекрасно получилось сегодня без потери качества и задержек с разрешением 1080 на 720

Comment: @eri, вести видео с usb камер и сохранять на ссд, можно купить видеорегистратор с ip камерами, однако даже голые платы поступают с ос только для чтения, соответственно там я делать ничего не смогу, если мне захочется наложить текст на видео или произвести какие-то действия в многопотоке

Comment: @andreymal, да, немного урезал задачу, у меня следующим этапом идёт наложение текста с датчиков на видео, желательно это делать параллельно

Comment: открыть доступ к ос видеорегистратора не сложно, но памяти на наложение текста там не хватит

Comment: Intel ищи, мощности побольше, чем у этих слабеньких плат.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую камеры со встроенным кодексом. Например logi c920 или ip камеры. Исключив перекодирование на процессоре платы можно передавать и больше трех потоков. Но это для простого стрима.

Для компьютерного зрения хочу попробовать ожноплатники nvidia.

Comment: К сожалению, одноплатник нвидиа стоит почти полторы штуки долларов, если вы о dragon 888

Comment: Зато умеет в нейросети и компьютерное зрение

Comment: khadas vim4 с головой хватит на нейронки и сложные вычисления

Comment: jetson стоит столько же

Comment: Почитай https://lwn.net/Articles/904776/, интересная статья по теме (ответа).

Comment: @0andriy,  Subscription required

Comment: Через неделю будет доступно всем. Могу прислать ссылку подписчика в приватный канал.